# Can a set of Euclidean distances be utilized as channel encoding?

Tags: finite-fields, information-theory, coding-theory

While star-gazing I tried to pick out some constellations and had difficulty identifying the correct sets of stars based on the shape alone. There were lots of stars that could have been as easily selected to make the right "shape"; some cloud cover might have also covered the "right" stars from view.

I wondered how ***specific*** the *inter-star* ***distances*** are in identifying the correct set of stars that belong to a constellation?

Explicitly, say there are 5 stars $A, B, C, D, E$ that belong to a constellation. And we knew the distance matrix between them:

```
   A  B  C  D  E
A  0  3  4  5  7
B  3  0  2  2  3
C  4  2  0  1  3
D  5  2  1  0  2
E  7  3  3  2  0
```

We observe 3 stars (say, A, D, E) that are fit this set of distances exactly {$5, 2$}. Is there an **information-theoretic measure** that describes the specificity of this observation? How many stars can we "skip" before we are no longer confident in this observation? Are there similar error-correcting codes based on this distance principle?

Comment: In an erasing channel, if a bit or symbol is erased we know that there was a symbol there and now we just don't know the value anymore but in your case, it seems that the problem is different and the whole thing might be deleted.
I suggest you anchor your constellation around a certain star that you know you won't miss and then based on that one you can define a regular or an erasing channel on whether the expected stars are observed or not.
Based on the number of constellations you want to detect, a minimum distance between codewords is forced upon you.

Comment: @mnz This is a good idea, one which illustrates my confusion. If one star is designated the "representative" of a constellation, how do we know if we've chosen the right star (too many to choose from)? However, if two stars are observed, and they are congruent with one of the pairwise distances in our constellation, how much more confident are we in detection (since there are much fewer "pairs" of stars that are separated by this distance)? What about three stars? Intuitively it feels that the specificity increases with the number of stars detected, but I would like to quantify this.

Comment: The idea here is I assume that your constellation does not rotate, so instead of distances you can exactly look at the corresponding place and check whether there is a start or a cloud. Since you are not designing the codeword but they are given to you, the things might not be as simple to formalize.
If you insist on using the distances I don't see a mapping between that formulation and what we have on coding theory available. On a side note, are the distances noisy or exact? and can the reverse of observation happen? (get a star when there is none?).

Comment: As an aside, stars do rotate! And the "reverse of observation" can indeed happen - such as when a bright object (ie. airplane) is confused with a real star.

Comment: But to generalize this problem outside of star gazing, what I'm thinking is if a "codeword" of pairwise distances is given, and the distances observed are noisy, how might one describe confidence in this decoding? Is this in some way similar to convolutional codes..?

Comment: Not that I have heard of. That's why I am trying to formalize your problem in terms of bits of being observed. So we can map it as a known channel coding problem.

Comment: This has some resemblance to the point set registration problem, might want to google the phrase.